# How to convert a tuple into a string in python and use it into strptime?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a list of tuples in Date[]: 
`[[2017, 1, 1], [2017, 1, 1], . . .`

How do I convert each of them into a string?

```py
X=[]
Y=[]
for i in range(len(Date)):
    if(Date[i][0]==2017):
        str=''.join(Date[i])
        X.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str, '%G %V %u').date())
        Y.append(Val[i])
```

strptime needs a str to convert, if i add Date[i] there, it says it accepts str not tuple. I tried converting it via `str=''join(Date[i])` but it says strptime accepts only str not ints. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: You have a list of lists.

Comment: What is Val[i] ?

Comment: Why do you need an if statement for 2017?

Comment: Because i want to filter out results from 2017 only thats why an if statement. The val[i] is another list that contains corresponding values for these dates. Weird enough, I tried converting it into list of tuples but results look the same. If printed on console, this shows as (2017,1,1) in round brackets not squared meaning it indeed is a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `strptime`, you could pass your values to `datetime.datetime` as they are

```
X.append(datetime.datetime(*Date[i]).date())
```

---

Also your code needs some polishing, variable names should be lower cased, instead of iterating over range you could iterate directly over values of `date` and `val`.

```
date = [[2017, 1, 1], [2017, 1, 1]]
val = [0, 1]

x = []
y = []
for i, v in zip(date, val):
    if i[0] == 2017:
        x.append(datetime.datetime(*i).date())
        y.append(v)
```

Comment: Gives error: ValueError: month must be in 1..12. Probably because I am Originally converting Isocalender weeks (tuple of year, weeknumber, weekday) into normal datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `datetime` instance out of your three parameters

```
dates = [[2017, 1, 1], [2017, 1, 1]]
X = []
for date in dates:
    if date[0] == 2017:
        dt = datetime.datetime(*date)
        X.append(dt.strftime('%G %V %u'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just initialize `datetime.date` object directly:

```
X.append(datetime.date(year=Date[i][0], month=Date[i][1], day=Date[i][2]))
```

Or even

```
X.append(datetime.date(*Date[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to map Date to a str by map and then join it with spaces solved the problem!

```py
X=[]
Y=[]
count=00
for i in range(len(Date)):
    if(Date[i][0]==2017):
        if (count>23):
            count=00
        sstr=' '.join(map(str,Date[i]))
        X.append(datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.strptime(sstr, '%G %V %u').date(),datetime.time(count,00)))
        #X.append(Date[i])
        Y.append(Val[i])
        count=count+1
```